# Swap out ListView item views

Tags: android, listview, view

I have a ListView that can be in one of two states - viewing and editing.

In viewing state, the ListView should use one view to render rows - one with non-editable fields.

In editing state, it should use another view - one with editable fields.

When the ListView switches between states, **all** its rows should use the appropriate view for that state.

If the user has scrolled down the list, he/she should not lose their position when the ListView transitons between viewing and editing.

One of the solutions I attempted involved 2 adapters.  But that was no good because it made the ListView pop back up to the first row whenever either adapter got set on the ListView.

Thanks much.

Comment: I am sorry but it's still not clear to me. Could you add a screenshot or describe your screen better so we can understand your problem? I  solve many problems of my own by just doing that.

Comment: i don't have a screenshot, but i've taken another stab at describing the use case.

Comment: That's much better and understandable now. But why can't you use just one adapter whose getView member method will switch off between editable and non-editable field?

Answer (score 1):

I've done something like this before. I had a set of complex views in a GalleryAdapter, one of which was a ViewFlipper that contained an EditText (the editable bit) and a TextView (the static part). There was a button to the right of the ViewFlipper, and when the user pressed that button I called `showNext()`/`showPrevious()` as appropriate to switch between the editable and visible views.

To clarify, I had one adapter that extended BaseAdapter, and in my `getView()` method I assigned onClickListeners to the buttons that would modify the objects in the view I was about to return.

Comment: That's a great way to switch one "row" between editable and visible views.  I need to switch all the rows to editable or visible views.

Comment: @Julian, sounds like you need to run the above methodology through a loop on all the rows, whenever anyone switches any of the rows.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel So keep references to all the row views somewhere and loop through that when switching?

Comment: Okay, so in your Adapter you'll be tracking the state of your views somewhere perhaps with a single boolean denoting in the adapter denoting if it's editable or not. Then all you need to do is flip that boolean and call ``notifyDataSetChanged()`` on your adapter, then all of your rows will change.